# What is the opposite of a hacker?

Tags: antonyms

In common parlance the term hacker can be used to describe a

> [person who illegally gains access to and sometimes tampers with information in a computer system](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hacker)

I wold like to know what term should be used to describe the opposite, namely someone who defends against a hacker to prevent the hacker from achieving her/his goal.

Comment: Hackers aren't only people who gain illegal access. There is such thing as an ethical hacker- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certified_Ethical_Hacker.

Comment: Yeah, "hacker", as a term for a computer geek, has a long history (back to the early 70s at least), and has had a range of meanings and implications.

Comment: @karlomanio "Ethical hacker" is almost an answer. Originally they penetrated system security, did no damage, but left calling cards hoping to be paid for consultancy work but now that's illegal and they are now contracted to do the same by invitation.

Comment: @BoldBen It is indeed...

Comment: They are guests then. Only your computer can invite them in.

Comment: 'hacker' has many meanings. I think you are thinking of the evil version of a hacker, and there the counterpart would be 'white hat' (where you really are thinking of a hacker as a black hat. Is that the case?

Answer (score 3):

A Computer Security Specialist. From [chron.com](https://work.chron.com/computer-security-specialist-do-13655.html):

> **What Does a Computer Security Specialist Do?**
>   Computer security is of utmost importance to company managers responsible for protecting their company’s information assets. Computer security specialists, or information security analysts, are responsible for protecting those assets on a day-to-day basis. A computer specialist’s job is to make sure only authorized people gain access to confidential information.

Comment: Also *Security Software Engineer* or *Cyber Security Engineer*

Answer (score 0):

Opposite of a hacker is a user. Someone who follows the rules and doesn't explore the system.

Comment: Please add a source to support your answer.

Comment: Probably accurate in isolation, but I think the question is asking for someone who specifically works against a hacker. Some good ideas in other answers considering the opposite of a soldier to be another soldier rather than the opposite of "soldier" being "civilian".